# TypeError: react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6___default.a.lazy is not a function for react@16.5.2

Tags: reactjs, webpack, lazy-loading

I'm trying to use `lazy loading` for my `create-react-app` with `react@16.5.2` and I did this :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const Header = React.lazy(() => import('./_header'));     

class SomeFile extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
          <React.Fragment>
            <Header  />
          </React.Fragment>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default SomeFile;
```

Do you know why this error occurs ? is it because of my react version ? based on [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html) everything seems fine!

## Edit

What does this mean? based on `reactjs.org` :

Note:

React.lazy and Suspense is not yet available for server-side rendering. If  you want to do code-splitting in a server rendered app, we recommend Loadable Components. It has a nice guide for bundle splitting with server-side rendering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

React.lazy is only available from v16.6.0 https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/10/23/react-v-16-6.html

Comment: I've updated my react vertion to react@16.6.3. The error changed to this : 
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Comment: Probably related to the fact that the component is not yet imported when you try to render it. Try using suspense https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/10/23/react-v-16-6.html#reactlazy-code-splitting-with-suspense

Comment: No I don't think that's because of suspense ! I think the thing that is returned differs.  I mean the Header component returns an abject instead of class.

Answer (score 0):

In your comand line interface, try updating React using the following command:

`npm i react@latest`

Restart Development Server, if you still face issue try the above steps:

Search for REACT_EDITOR on the Readme.md file, and insert `=atom` in front of it, like as follow:

`REACT_EDITOR=atom`

Then, save, restart the development server. It should work now